# Paperclip S3 encryption rails

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

Mine is more of a question than a code problem, I have been trying to read about this for a while and I have not found an answer. My question is if amazon S3 automatically encrypts the data when it is uploaded to it or do we have to encrypt the data before we up load to S3. If we have to encrypt the data before we upload it can anyone recommend what gem to use and how.

Answer (score 1):

It is not my experience that all files uploaded to S3 are encrypted by default.

Certainly this is not the case with Paperclip 3.3.1, as the S3 web console shows 'Server Side Encryption: None' for a document uploaded by this version with default attachment options.

However, Paperclip does support adding the `x-amz-server-side-encryption` header to the upload request via the `s3_server_side_encryption` option.

```
has_attached_file :file, s3_permissions: :private,
                         s3_server_side_encryption: :aes256
```

Should result in the desired behavior, but it doesn't. The following works, by manually setting this header, until [pull request  1398](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/1398) is merged, making the above work as expected.

```
has_attached_file :file, s3_permissions: :private,
                         s3_headers: { "x-amz-server-side-encryption" => "AES256" }
```

I confirmed that this 2nd configuration results in 'Server Side Encryption: AES-256' being indicated in the web console. Also confirmed using the fork referenced in the pull request and the first code snippet.

I added a wiki page for this, as documentation was lacking.

[Paperclip Wiki Document on Encryption](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Encryption-on-amazon-s3)
[AWS SSE Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingRESTAPI.html)
[Originating Paperclip Issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/697)

Answer (score -3):

All S3 content is encrypted by default. As additional security measurement you can encrypt it on your own. You can use for example this : https://github.com/tcnijmeijer/aws-s3-cse for client side encryption.

Here is Amazon S3 documentation mentioning client-side encryption : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just to clarify Amazon S3's server-side encryption is done as soon as the file is uploaded. I only repeat the question because this is my first project that I have built in Rails and S3. I was also looking at the this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingRubySDK.html. It seems to say that I have to specify Sever-side Encryption, or am I reading it incorrectly.

Comment: All S3 content is **not** encrypted by default. Not sure if this used to be true, but objects uploaded with Paperclip to S3 with default options are certainly not stored with encryption, which is what the question is referencing.

Comment: S3 files are not encrypted by default. However it is very simple to enable encryption by adding the x-amz-server-side-encryption header to request the file be encrypted.